# SSTable multiple directories

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have recently started working on Cassandra everything was well documented and easy to understand so far.

However I am unable to find any answer to the following question:

Why do Cassandra data directory (/var/lib/cassandra/data/ks) have multiple subdirectories for the same SSTable? 
At why what point is the new directory is created?

```html
[centos@cs1 2017-06-03--19-46-14 cassandra $] ls -l /var/lib/cassandra/data/ks
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Jun  3 19:46 events-4f35e2c0482911e79119511599d22fe7
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Jun  3 19:41 events-7a34c34047f411e7aee3b9dc2549db1c

[centos@cs1 2017-06-03--19-46-10 cassandra $] tree
.
├── events-4f35e2c0482911e79119511599d22fe7
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-CompressionInfo.db
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-Data.db
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-Digest.sha1
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-Filter.db
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-Index.db
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-Statistics.db
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-Summary.db
│   ├── ks-events-ka-4-TOC.txt
│   └── snapshots
└── events-7a34c34047f411e7aee3b9dc2549db1c
    └── snapshots
        └── 1496472654574-device_log
            └── manifest.json

5 directories, 9 files
```

I noticed that flushing or compacting does not create new directory. It Simply adds/compacts the most recent SSTable directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop a table, by default Cassandra takes a snapshot to prevent data-loss if it was unintended. In your case, the events-7a34c34047f411e7aee3b9dc2549db1c is the older table and it has only snapshot directory in it.

The Cassandra.yaml parameter responsible for that action is as follows

> auto_snapshot  (Default: true) Enable or disable whether a snapshot
>   is taken of the data before keyspace truncation or dropping of tables.
>   To prevent data loss, using the default setting is strongly advised.
>   If you set to false, you will lose data on truncation or drop.

Remember to clean up the older table snapshots in production like environments, otherwise it could easily pile up on the data directory size.

Comment: That helps. Thanks!
But shouldn't the corresponding sstable directories be cleanedup when you drop a keyspace

Comment: Apparently it doesn't because auto_snapshot is set to true. So drop keyspace would result in, snapshots for all the tables within that keyspace.  If the entire keyspace sstable directory gets dropped, you just lost the safety valve. So its for our safe keeping that the Keyspace drop doesn't end up dropping the directory. Try setting auto_snapshot to FALSE and then drop keyspace it would drop the directories. **But guess what, its dangerous!**

Comment: Also, one thing to notice is they auto_snapshot:false will not delete the SSTable directories. It only means do not snapshot my SSTables if keyspace is deleted

Answer (score 0):

If you drop a keyspace (ks as in my case) it does not deletes the keyspace directory (/var/lib/cassandra/data/ks) from the filesystem (auto_snapshot:true). That was the reason I was still seeing old - directory/s.

Answer (score 0):

In cassandra when you drop a table, it's directory is remain in KeySpace directory.
In your case, it seems you created a table with name of the table you dropped before. because of that you have one table with two directory that one of those is useless, and you can rm -rf its directory or run nodetool clearsnapshot.